# Ionic/Cordova app debug on windows phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, ionic-framework

I successfully developed Ionic-Cordova project for Android & iOS platforms. But if the same code base is used for windows phone 8 (wp8) build, so many issues are coming like animations are not smooth, sidemenu is not working properly etc.

As i read in ionic website, Ionic is not supporting windows platform and its support is on roadmap.

I am not able to debug the app just like android remote USB debugging. I also tried **weinre** but I faced so many issues with weinre:

1. It is not allowing us to debug javascript code.
2. It is just showing inline styles but not css classes.
3. We are unable to select particular html element directly to check the styles. For this we must traverse from html tag to find the element.

What is the best way to debug windows-phone-8(wp8) (or) windows phone 8.1 apps?

Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If it's Windows Phone 8.1, Visual Studio 2013 includes a web debugger. If it's Windows Phone 8, it's very difficult to debug. I had problems with Weinre.

Comment: If I want to use Windows Phone 8.1, which platform I need to add using cordova? Is it "cordova platform add windows"?

Can I use Visual Studio 2013 Community edition? Do I need to install apache cordova tools for visual studio?

Comment: Yep, `cordova platform add windows` will do it. I am not sure about Community Edition - as I don't use it. I presume so - as long as Community Edition supports Windows Phone 8.1 projects. No you don't - that's only to enable integration to Cordova, but it's not essential.

Comment: Thanks you so much@keldar. Once I add windows platform and build windows project using 'cordova build windows', CordovaApp.sln file has been created. How to run my project in windows phone emulator.

Comment: Hi Sivakumar, if you press play at the top and ensure "emulator" is selected, it will deploy to the simulator.

Comment: Keldar, I already tried to play with "Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512 MB". It is opening windows emulator and saying that "Windows phone OS is starting...". At last it is giving an error "Device can not be found. App deployment failed"

Comment: Does the emulator ever load?

Comment: No. But I am able to deploy it on mobile :-). Which hybrid framework you are using for windows phone apps?